# fetch error 'return undefined' in app.js ('data is not defined') with React

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I'm working on a node js and react app. I'm trying to fetch the following dataset from my back-end:

```
    [{"name":"nameonehere#1"},{"name":"nameonehere#2"},
{"name":"nameonehere#3"},{"nameonehere#4"},...,{"name":"nameonehere#xxx"}]
```

Here is my app.js:

```
class App extends Component {
state = {
    data: null,
    loading: true,
    error: false
  };

    componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/getData')
      .then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw res;
        }
        return res.json()
      }).then(data => {
        // setState triggers re-render
        this.setState({loading: false, data});
      }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        this.setState({loading: false, error: true});
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
...
            <div>
        {this.state.loading ? <p>Loading...</p>
          : this.state.error ? <p>Error during fetch!</p>
          : (
              <ul>
                this.state.data.map(data =>
                <div key={data.id}>data: {data.name}</div>)
              </ul>
            )}
            </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and I have the following error `'data' is not defined`

the error is line 80 which is this line of code:

`<div key={data.id}>data: {data.name}</div>)`

I tried a few things but nothing is working. I'm a bit lost between JS and JSX.

What is the issue?

Comment: It says state.datas (with an s). Also' at what line do you get the error?

Comment: I would say the same, although `'data' is not defined` doesn't make sense then, but that could be a typo to SO offcourse.

Comment: This is not a typo. I've updated my question about the line code error. the type was in the question not in the real code :p

Comment: how `data` looks like when returned from your API?

Comment: when opening the http://localhost:5000/getData I have the data exactly as I shared them as the beginning of my question. Is this answering your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to open `{ }` when doing the `this.state.data.map`

It's considering that as text and failling on the `key` which tries to get a `data` variable.

You should add the brackets like so:

```
<ul>
    {
        this.state.data.map(data => <div key={data.id}>data: {data.name}</div>)
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write an expression in JSX you wrap it in curly braces
So you need to wrap your map inside it as so

```
{
 this.state.data.map(data =>
 <div key={data.id}>data: {data.name}</div>
}
```

Hope this helps